# FIRMessagingDelegate's-messaging:didReceiveMessage: not implemented - Firebase 4.1.1 - Swift 3

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging, ios10, appdelegate

I upgraded Firebase from `v3` to `v4` but I have some problems in receiving messages and I get this warning:

> [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002019] FIRMessaging received data-message, but FIRMessagingDelegate's-messaging:didReceiveMessage: not implemented

I know I should implement this method :

```
public func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage){
    print(remoteMessage.appData)
            //let title = remoteMessage.appData[("data"): {"title"}]
           var title = "New Request"

            for value in remoteMessage.appData{
                if let value = value as?  [AnyHashable:Any]{
                print(value)
                }
            }
            let message = "okay"
            print(message)
             self.showAlertAppDelegate(title: title ,message:message ,buttonTitle:"ok",window:self.window!)
            print(title, message)

}
```

But I still have the warning so is there any actions should I do more ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the problem, which is I forgot this line

```
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
```

in this method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
               didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {}
```

Comment: and function didFinishLaunchingWithOption be make public